C# HttpClient do not send Server Name Identification
I need to find a way to disable C# HttpClient Server Name Identification to evade ISP "dangerous sites filter" block that blocks the API I'm trying to retrieve data from.
It is not possible to contact the ISP and get it removed from blacklist, they don't budge.
In curl we can simply send the host header and it'll pass Server Name Identification would be IP Adress of the server. We do not care about MITM attack in this scenario since data coming is public data that does not need any form security (Weather Data). Thus not verifying authenticity is ok and is not relevant to the question since all I need is the data not the security.
In C# HttpClient for some reason wants to send whatever is in the host header in the SNI.
Is there a way to disable this annoying behavior?
I don't want to call the curl and take it's response since it's slower and less reliable also locks up the asp net core app.

Apparently it is possible to customize SNI in NET.
Based on: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/httpclient-sni
       HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new SocketsHttpHandler() {
            SslOptions = new System.Net.Security.SslClientAuthenticationOptions() {
                RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate {return true;}
            },
            ConnectCallback = async (context, cancellationToken) =>
        {
            var socket = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) { NoDelay = true };
            try
            {
                await socket.ConnectAsync(context.DnsEndPoint, cancellationToken);
    
                var sslStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(socket, ownsSocket: true));
    
                await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync(new SslClientAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    TargetHost = "veryverybadisp",
                    RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = delegate {return true;}                
    
                }, cancellationToken);
    
                return sslStream;
            }
            catch
            {
                socket.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }
        });


This code simply changes SNI to "veryverybadisp" allowing sending requests that can have different host headers than SNI. This code also disables checking certificate. Not very secure but anyways something dumb might require obscure solutions.
